# .htaccess - Force .SVG files to download

Tags: .htaccess, mime-types, content-type

I'm building a brands page for my website and would like to allow users to download various versions of my logo's and brands, however I seem to be having some issues forcing .svg files to download instead of be viewable in the browser.

I've been playing around with .htaccess and I've been able to my .png and .gif but have been unsuccessful in getting my .svg files to download. Here are the methods I've tried:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|svg)$">
   ForceType application/octet-stream
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

---

```
AddType application/octet-stream .png
AddType application/octet-stream .svg
```

---

```
<Files *.svg>
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working but I think it may have something to do with the fact that svg documents aren't actually images. I'll be very appreciative of any help provided and thank you in advance for taking the time to read this.

Comment: What browser are you testing this on? Have you checked in the browser's page info that the mime-type you're setting is what the browser actually receives?